# How to interpret hard negative mining curves while training a deep object detector?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection, model-evaluations

I am training a single shot detector (SSD) in tensorflow object detection API. After having read the paper and some articles online, I understood that hard negative mining trains the network on 'hard examples', and that the number of 'mined' negatives shouldn't outnumber the positives to ensure that data stay balanced. But I am still unable to fully grasp the curves that I get throughout training:

[image]

This is my hard miner configuration:

hard_example_miner {

```
    num_hard_examples: 3000
    iou_threshold: 0.990000009537
    loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
    max_negatives_per_positive: 3
    min_negatives_per_image: 3
  }
```

SSD is using 3:1 as ratio between negatives and positives, and this shows in the figures.

I understand that the left figure is the number of negatives per step that the network is trained on.

Is the right figure there to only show the number of positives that the network has found for each step?

Isn't it a bad sign that the number of positives is decreasing?